# Per-project tasks in SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

My .sbt file looks something like this:

```
lazy val common = (project in file("./common"))
  .settings(
    // other settings
  )
lazy val one = (project in file("./one"))
  .dependsOn(common)
  .settings(
    // other settings
    addCommandAlias("build", ";clean;assembly;foo")
  )
lazy val two = (project in file("./two"))
  .dependsOn(common)
  .settings(
    // other settings
    addCommandAlias("build", ";clean;compile;bar")
  )
```

Additionally I have two tasks `foo` and `bar` which are only valid in their respective projects.

My tests show that upon calling `build` - no matter which project I am in - both aliases are being called.

And for tasks, the keys can already be only defined at top-level of the .sbt file (e.g. `val foo = taskKey[Unit]("Does foo")`).

I want to know how to correctly implement tasks and command aliases on project level.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is with alias in sbt. When an alias is defined, it is attached to scope `GlobalScope` in the form of a command and therefore available for all sub-projects. When you do multiple definitions of aliases with `addCommandAlias`, the last execution wins as every executions removes previously created alias with the same name.

You can see the defined alias by running `sbt alias` and it will print that there is only one `build` alias.

You could achieve separations of `build` by introducing it as a `taskKey`

```
lazy val build = taskKey[Unit]("Builds")

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .aggregate(one, two) // THIS IS NEED TO MAKE build TASK AVAILABLE IN ROOT

lazy val common = (project in file("./common"))
  .settings(
    //SOME KEYS
  )

lazy val one = (project in file("./one"))
  .dependsOn(common)
  .settings(
    build := {
      Def.sequential(clean, Compile / compile).value
    }
  )

lazy val two = (project in file("./two"))
  .dependsOn(common)
  .settings(
    build := {
      Def.sequential(clean, assembly).value
    }
  )
```

EDIT: Added `Def.sequential` as suggested by @laughedelic in the comments

Comment: Ah thank you. What happens when I call `build` in root project without using `aggregate`? The `taskKey` is already defined, but it's behaviour is not... (?)

Comment: It will say something like `[error] Not a valid command: build`

Comment: You should use `Def.sequential` to run tasks one after another. Check https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Howto-Sequential-Task.html

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc so I tried this approach but I can still call `build` at root level... It fails horribly once it comes across undefined commands but still...